# typeof returns string but console logs [object Object]

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, protractor, automated-tests

In my Protractor code, I noticed this strange behavior:

```
let foo = getElementText(element(by.xpath("//wha/t/e/v/e/r")))
console.log(typeof foo) // logs "string"
console.log("foo is " + foo) // logs "[object Object]"

function getElementText(element){
  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions
  browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element), 5000)
  var elementText = element.getText().toString()
  console.log(typeof elementText)
  return elementText
}
```

It doesn't change anything if I try `foo.toString()`.

I would like to log the value of `foo`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of everything you're doing here - but `getElementText` returns `element.getText().toString()` so it's the string representation of `element.getText()`. So no wonder it's of type String, and if `element.getText()` is an object then it will indeed be `[object Object]`.

Comment: Sounds like `foo` is actually the string `"[object Object]"`. What does `element.getText()` return?

Comment: @Phil, in this case `element.getText()` should return the name of a city. There's no reason it should return the string `"[object Object]"` :s

Comment: @Y-BCause prove it. Do some debugging

Comment: `element.getText()` returns a promise. See the documentation ~ https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText

Comment: @Phil Oh, okay... Too bad I didn't RTFM :p Coming from Selenium Java I was expecting things to be similar, but they aren't. Still, I tried this but with any valid xPath it returns me `undefined`... `function getElementText(element){
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element), 10000)
    var elementText = element.getText().then(function(){
      console.log(typeof elementText)
      return elementText
    });
  }` This is driving me crazy...

Comment: For that one, you want [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### suggestion: migrate off of the control flow

I would strongly suggest moving off of the control flow and using async / await. When using the control flow, Protractor queues up all the async calls and executes them in order and does not actually run them line by line. See https://youtu.be/6aPfHrSl0Qk?t=976 (where we discuss control flow being deprecated and what Protractor is actually doing behind the scenes).

#### discussion: promises not making it onto the control flow

So why does this not work? Protractor takes the `getElementText` function and assumes this might be thenable and puts it in the queue. That's great; however, the queue does not know that `browser.wait` and `getText` are thenable so it does not actually wait for them.

#### guesses at why it is printing what it's printing

Why are you getting that text in that order? I am going to make a few guesses. If you execute the `getElementText` without putting things on the control flow, it does not wait for the `browser.wait` then on the next line `var elementText = element.getText().toString()` turns the promise to a string and it prints "string". The next thing that happens is that `console.log(typeof foo)` prints the typeof `webdriver.Promise<string>` which is `[Object object]`. I am not sure why there is no logging for `"foo is " + foo`. It does not show up in your logging.

#### the fix in the control flow

(although if you use the control flow, you won't have this problem)

```
let foo = getElementText(element(by.xpath("//wha/t/e/v/e/r")))
console.log(typeof foo);
console.log("foo is " + foo);

function getElementText(element) {
  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions
  return browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element), 5000).then(() => {
    return element.getText().then(elementText => {

      // print stuff
      console.log(typeof elementText);
      console.log(elementText);
      return elementText;
    });
  });
}
```

#### the fix async / await (and TypeScript)

Things are easier with type checking and async / await:

```
let foo = await getElementText(element(by.xpath("//wha/t/e/v/e/r")));
console.log(typeof foo);
console.log("foo is " + foo);

// prefer renaming element to something else since it is a Protractor API.
async function getElementText(elementWithText): Promise<string> {
  const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

  // I can't remember if you need to await EC.visibilityOf(elementWithText).
  // I think you need to
  await browser.wait(await EC.visibilityOf(elementWithText), 5000);
  const elementText = await element.getText();
  console.log(typeof elementText);
  console.log(elementText);
  return elementText;
}
```

Hope that helps (also upvote if this works).

Answer (score 1):

```
let foo = getElementText(element(by.xpath("//wha/t/e/v/e/r")))
console.log(typeof foo) // logs "string"
console.log("foo is " + foo) // logs "[object Object]"
```

3rd statement prints value of foo before even 1st statement is executed properly. Return type for element.getText() is promise.Promise. One needs to resolve promise, make function async and use awaits.